# How to get the project which belongs specific user

Tags: laravel

### **Database**

i have 3 tables users, posts and post_user

```
users table     projects table      project_user table
---------       ---------           --------------------
id | name       id | name           project_id | user_id
---------       ---------           --------------------
1  | user1      1  | pr1            1      |    1
2  | user2      2  | pr2            2      |    1
---------       3  | Pr3            3      |    2
                ---------          --------------------
```

**Models**

## User Model

---

```
public function projects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
}
```

## Project Model

---

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

The project is written by laravel 8.x
Now in controller and view how to get all the projects which belongs specific user id.
all i need is to display the projects of the logged in user using laravel.

Comment: Please show us what you tryied so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$projects = App\User::find(5)->projects;
```

This will get all projects for a user of ID 5.

You of course need to import the class like App\User::find, or have `use App\User` in top of PHP file.

For further clarity on what is going on:

- `User::find(5)` - returns the user with ID 5 (or whatever is your primary key field)
- `->projects` is a magic method which will return all results for the relationship defined in the projects() method of the User class.
- Had we done `->projects()` (instead of `->projects`) we would instead receive the Query Builder object for the relationship which we could chain more query arguments onto (such as `->where()` or `->limit(x)` etc) and finally could call `->get()` to return the results (Collection) of the query.

Comment: This assumes you have correctly set up your database with a pivot table.

Comment: Sorry, but how can i limit this to 10 rows only

Comment: Sorry, but how can i limit this to 10 rows only $projects = App\User::find(5)->projects; @benjaminhull

Comment: Yes, just do ->projects()->limit(5)->get(). Using ->projects immediately calls the query and returns the results for all related items. Using ->projects() gets the query builder instance, which means you can then add further bits to the query.